# Negative pending messages in ActiveMQ

Tags: linux, activemq, message-queuing

We have a cluster of 6 ActiveMQ nodes. ActiveMQ version is 5.15.8 on all nodes. The problem is that we randomly face negative count of pending messages on brokers. We googled the issue and found that some fellows have the same issue on older versions. But we could not find a proper answer whether the problem has been resolved or not! Does anybody have any updated information about this bug? Is it resolved in upper versions or not?

Comment: mostly regarding clusters it might an issue on the system time. do you use the same time source?

Comment: Yes we have a central time server for all servers on the local network.